# Should a UIView Observe Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am working in iOS and I have a custom view,

```
class MyView: UIView {

}
```

One of my `ViewControllers` is using the custom view like,

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    viewDidLoad(){
        let view = MyView() // ...
    }

}
```

My custom view `MyView` requires to observe a notification so I have added it inside `MyView's` init and removed in `dealoc` block like,

```
class MyView: UIView {

    init() {
        addObserver(...)
    }

    dealloc {
        removeObserver(...)
    }
}
```

One of my colleagues commented that the View should not be responsible to handle observer rather associated `ViewControllers` should handle it. Is there any problem of my design? What are the issues I might face in future if I follow my current design?

Comment: one note from my side: "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method" [from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1407263-removeobserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following best modelling practices with MVC/MVVM or similar, your views should be as 'dumb' as possible, and just render what they are told to by the ViewController.

Adding an observer to a UIView directly strongly couples that view to your application logic. This makes the view less reusable and results in your application logic being more difficult to reason about and test if that logic is split between this view and its controller.